# Ddos Protection syntax - Nginx

Tags: nginx, ddos

I am using this syntax for my Nginx configuration file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` which reads:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

events {
worker_connections 2048;
multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

client_header_buffer_size 2k;
large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

client_body_buffer_size 10M;
client_max_body_size 10M;

client_body_timeout 12;
client_header_timeout 12;
keepalive_timeout 15;
send_timeout 10;

limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m;
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit_per_ip:10m rate=50r/s;

server {
limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 10;
limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=10 nodelay;
}

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

My websites server blocks are included within: `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`

Is the server defined within `http` as seen above going to supersede the `server{}` blocks in my `sites-enabled/*` so that DDOS protection will work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is an important difference between **DOS** and **DDOS** attacks. The additional D in DDOS stands for distributed.

For simple **DOS** attacks your setup can be used. However it really depends on your application or website where the difference between an allowed or expected use case and a not allowed or not expected use case might be. There exists no generic recipe.

To mitigate **DDOS** attacks your setup **will not help**. Such attacks will be fired from many different IP addresses. Usually DDOS attacks must be mitigated on network level and with a really high bandwith.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're talking about [ngx_http_limit_conn_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html) and [ngx_http_limit_req_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html).

> Syntax:   limit_conn zone number;
> Default:  —
> Context:  http, server, location
> These directives are inherited from the previous configuration level if and only if there are no limit_conn directives defined on the current level.

So for `limit_conn` you need to place it one level up into the `http` block to make it inherited into the `server` blocks.

> Syntax:   limit_req zone=name [burst=number] [nodelay | delay=number];
> Default:  —
> Context:  http, server, location
> These directives are inherited from the previous configuration level if and only if there are no limit_req directives defined on the current level.

Same for the `limit_req` place it one level up into the `http` block to make it inherited into the `server` block.